Maximize volume of tetrahedron $ABCD$ given $AC=AD=BC=BD=1$

In tetrahedron $ABCD$, the edges $AC$, $AD$, $BC$, $BD$ are all of length $1$. Find the maximum value of the volume of the tetrahedron.

Here is my solution: let $CD=x$, then $x\in(0,2)$ by the triangle inequality.
Hence, the base $\triangle BCD$ has area $\frac x2\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x2\right)^2}$.
The height, which is the distance from $A$ to plane $BCD$, is no more than the distance from $A$ to line $CD$, which is $\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x2\right)^2}$, and equality can be obtained when planes $ADC\perp BDC$.
So maximum volume is
$$\frac13\cdot\frac x2\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x2\right)^2}\cdot\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x2\right)^2}=\cdots\le\frac{2\sqrt3}{27}.$$
Equality can be obtained when $x=\frac{2\sqrt3}3$.
But the answer should be $\frac12$, so which step is incorrect?
Edit. My answer was correct and the book I used made a mistake.

I might have mixed up the point names.  I did the same calculations using A = [1, 0, 0] B = [cos(t), 0, sin(t)] C = [cos(t) + 1, sqrt(2cos(t) + 2), sin(t)] / 2 (which is the same as saying that C is 1 away from A and B and directly over their midpoint).  Then calculated the area using the determinant.  Got the same result you did.  Maximized when cos(t) = 1/3.  The only thing I can see that could be wrong is the assumption that volume is maximized when C is directly over the midpoints, but it sounds right to me.

In hindsight, a better parameterization would have been A = [cos(t), 0, sin(t)], B = [cos(t), 0, -sin(t)], C = [cos(t), cos(t), 0].

If you use C = [cos(t) + cos(t)cos(s), cos(t)sin(s), 0], with the above A, B, you get the full freedom of the tetrahedron.  And a volume of sin(s) cos(t)^2 sin(t) .  And this nice desmos plot https://www.desmos.com/3d/ueni3l51c7 .  And still the same answer.

@DanielV The "answer" was wrong as the maximum volume should just be $\frac{2\sqrt3}{27}$, thanks for your help. I will delete this soon.

I don't think it should be deleted, just edit to clarify the book was wrong.  Someone else using the same book may find it useful.
